# How to disable button if two or more editText is empty using viewmodel and livedata?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, viewmodel, android-livedata

I am able to disable/enable the button for only one field, but not for
How to disable button if two or more editText is empty using viewmodel and livedata?

I have tried this function  fun disableButton() {
isButtonEnabled.value =
!(login.value?.isBlank() == true && name.value?.isBlank() == true && password.value?.isBlank() == true && repeatPassword.value?.isBlank() == true)
}

```
class RegistrationVM @Inject constructor() : ViewModel() {

    val isButtonEnabled = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val login = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val loginError = MutableLiveData<String?>()
    val name = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val nameError = MutableLiveData<String?>()
    val password = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val passwordError = MutableLiveData<String?>()
    val repeatPassword = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val repeatPasswordError = MutableLiveData<String?>()

    fun loginValidation(input: String) {
        login.value = input
        loginError.value = if (input.length < 8) "Minimum 8 character" else null
    }

    fun nameValidation(input: String) {
        name.value = input
    }

    fun passwordValidation(input: String) {
        password.value = input
        passwordError.value = if (input.length < 8) "Minimum 8 character" else null
    }

    fun repeatPasswordValidation(input: String) {
        repeatPassword.value = input
        repeatPasswordError.value = if (input.length < 8) "Minimum 8 character" else null
    }
}
```

class RegistrationFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_registration) {

```
private val vm by viewModels<RegistrationVM>()

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    val binding = FragmentRegistrationBinding.bind(view)
    binding.loginInput.doAfterTextChanged {
        vm.loginValidation(it.toString())
    }
    vm.loginError.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
        binding.loginField.error = it
    }
    binding.nameInput.doAfterTextChanged {
        vm.nameValidation(it.toString())
    }
    vm.nameError.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
        binding.nameField.error = it
    }
    binding.passwordInput.doAfterTextChanged {
        vm.passwordValidation(it.toString())
    }
    vm.passwordError.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
        binding.passwordField.error = it
    }
    binding.repeatPasswordInput.doAfterTextChanged {
        vm.repeatPasswordValidation(it.toString())
    }
    vm.repeatPasswordError.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
        binding.repeatPasswordField.error = it
    }

    vm.isButtonEnabled.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
        binding.createAccount.isEnabled = it
    }
    binding.createAccount.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Account created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you mean by _"block[ing]"_, but if you want to merge multiple livedatas into one livedata you can use `MediatorLiveData`.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

how are you?

If your objective is to monitor all fields to enable the button just if all required fields are filled, there is a more straightforward way to do it that doesn’t have to use ViewModel/LiveData.

First, you define a listener that will monitor the EditText changes. This listener will receive some parameters, one of them is the count, which is the count of chars on the EditText. We can use it to disable the button if the char count is equal to zero and, if it's different from zero, we check if all the other EditText is filled, if true, we can enable the button. So, the implementation of this listener will be like this:

```
    private val controlButtonEnabledWhenTextChanged = { _: CharSequence?, _: Int, _: Int, count: Int ->
        binding.buttonFirst.isEnabled = areAllFieldsFilled()
    }

    private fun areAllFieldsFilled(): Boolean {
        return binding.firstName.text.isNotBlank() && binding.lastName.text.isNotBlank()
    }
```

Then, you need to add this listener to all EditText you want to monitor:

```
binding.firstName.addTextChangedListener(onTextChanged = controlButtonEnabledWhenTextChanged)
binding.lastName.addTextChangedListener(onTextChanged = controlButtonEnabledWhenTextChanged)
```

This implementation is simpler to understand and I believe that it solves your problem.

Comment: Don't forget to define the button disabled by default on XML